# Generic Extension

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to create a generic IsEmpty extension but am having problems specifically with dictionaries:

The functions I have created:

```
<Extension()> Function IsEmpty(null As DBNull) As Boolean
  Return True
End Function

<Extension()> Function IsEmpty(d As Date) As Boolean
  Return d = New Date
End Function

<Extension()> Function IsEmpty(s As String) As Boolean
  Return s Is Nothing OrElse s.Length = 0
End Function

<Extension()> Function IsEmpty(a As Array) As Boolean
  Return a Is Nothing OrElse a.Length = 0
End Function

<Extension()> Function IsEmpty(collection As ICollection) As Boolean
  Return collection Is Nothing OrElse collection.Count = 0
End Function

<Extension()> Function IsEmpty(Of T)(val As T) As Boolean
  Return False
End Function
```

For my purposes, booleans and numerics are never "empty".

The problem is that dictionaries are using the generic (Of T)(val As T) function instead of the (collection As ICollection) function.

i.e.

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String,String)
Response.Write(dict.IsEmpty)
```

output is "False"

I tried using (Of K,V)(collection As ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of K,V))) to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your overload:

```
Function IsEmpty(Of T)(val As T) As Boolean
```

becomes more specific than:

```
Function IsEmpty(collection As ICollection) As Boolean
```

The compiler will choose the generic overload first, because it can specify `T` to be a `Dictionary(of String, String)` which is more specific than an `ICollection`. If you change the generic method to simply take an object, the `ICollection` overload will be more specific, and be selected by the compiler:

```
Function IsEmpty(val As Object) As Boolean
```

Comment: Thanks, that does explain it.  Is the only way to avoid the boxing involved in using an Object to specify an IsEmpty function for every common type?

Comment: Only for every common value type. Remember that only value types (types defined as `struct`, not `class`) can be boxed/unboxed.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the last overload to take `System.Object` as the parameter. That would get lowest priority which is what you want, I think.

The compiler likes the current one better than the overload for ICollection because casting to ICollection would be a type conversion. By taking any type it is not considered a type conversion so it gets higher priority.

Comment: OK, that does fix the problem.  I was trying to avoid boxing/unboxing.  I would still like to understand why the (Of T) function is being chosen as more specific than the ICollection one.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of specificity.

Comment: Is the only way to avoid the boxing involved in using an Object to specify an IsEmpty function for every common type?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are writing extension methods correctly for VB.Net, for starters.

**edit**
Okay, looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx), you are using mostly correct formatting. You need to do something like this, though:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Module1

    Private dict As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Sub Main()
        If dict.IsEmpty() Then
            Console.WriteLine("We're Empty")
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    <Extension()> Function IsEmpty(Of TKey, TVal)(ByRef collection As Dictionary(Of TKey, TVal)) As Boolean
        Return collection Is Nothing OrElse Collection.Count = 0
    End Function

End Module
```

In order for your extension method to work properly, you needed the `ByRef` in the parameter (as I understand it from MSDN). Anyway, the above example works as is.